# request.get is blocked(python)

Tags: web-crawler

guys.
i have a some question about crawling
when i use request.get to get text, but it give to me 'sorry, you have been blocked' as below picture. how do i have to fix it?

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os

    req = requests.get('url')
    req.encoding='utf-8'

    html = req.text
    print(html)
```

[image]